# Can an employee receive commission for buying products from a company?

Tags: halal-haram, money, work

My husband works in a company where he has to purchase products for the company. Vendor gives commission on every product they purchase. Like if the product is 850$ then they will make a receipt of 950$. 100$ is purchaser commission. They do so to make their clients permanently. Is this commission is halal or haram?

Comment: Sorry question is confusing. Is he purchasing it for $850 then selling it for $950, or acting as a middle man by delivering the product and charging $950 taking $100 for himself and $850 for the company?

Comment: Does the company your husband works for pay monthly salary for the job he is doing?

Comment: No, actual price is 850 but the receipt for company will be made of 950. 100 for my husband. Company will give extra 100.

Comment: And this is not my husband's duty to purchase. This is his extra work.

Answer (score 2):

Well as far as i understand (please correct me if i'm misunderstanding), we have the following Situation:

The Products value is 850$

The Price the Company of your Husband pays is 950$

The vendor gives your Husband the difference right?

Now as your Husband is or should be payed from his company this would be a bribery and this is clearly haram as this should be his job. Now if he wasn't payed for such things the matter would be different. As i know -from telling- that this even happens in Muslim countries this is a very dark twilight zone and to me it sounds and feels like bribery, but Allah knows best!

See also this [fatwa](http://islamqa.info/en/21980)

Normally it would be Halal if the Vendor made a better offer proposal (for example Market price 850$ and your Price 800$) to *the company*. And maybe small gifts would be OK, as i know that for building up a relationship between two companies this is more or less usual for example when you visit the "partner" and both give each other some small gifts like souvenirs and stuff reciprocally.

And if your husband was not working for the company who buy the products then he could get a commission if he can convince the company to buy the product even from both company's as reward for his effort.

Answer (score 1):

**Salaam to my brothers and sisters out there.**

Everyone has their own ethics and beliefs - Islam leaves nothing in the middle - our mind has the power to understand if it is wrong or right -

Wrong - If somebody is facing troubles - emotionally or financially to your husbands decisions or not.

Right - if everyone is okay knowing about it.

I work in an organization where I sell something for a certain price - whatever price I sell at - I get a %age on that amount.

I am not hiding from everyone - the company pays me this %age and basic salary both - Company knows
The customer I'm selling to, knows I earn something from what they pay - they know

As far as I have nothing to hide from the people of Allah, I may not need be afraid of my decisions - yes if I was doing sales for this company, taking commissions from the company and on the side taking it from the client too - without the consent of the company then it would have been wrong.

There is a very thin line between haraam and halaal in commissions that is why it is recommended to rather than asking around - be honest to yourself and know if its wrong or right.

Answer (score 0):

Assalaam Aleykum

The commission will be halal only if the  company knows about it and allows the buyer/their employee to keep the $100, the person buying from the vendor is a servant of the company but the actually buyer is the company/his master. Hence Islam prohibits all forms of deceit and anything got through deceit is haram. And Allah knows best.